# Trying to write a function that receives a number argument and check and print if the number is positive, negative, or zero (Python 3)

Tags: python, if-statement, input

### Here is my code to check is the number is positive, negative or zero.

```
x = input("Enter a number to check if it is positive, negative or zero.")
def function():
    if x == 0:
    print("The number is zero.")
    
    elif x > 0: 
    print("The number is positive.")
    
    elif x < 0:
    print("The number is negative.")
```

---

**Here is the error I get**

```
File "<string>", line 4
    print("The number is zero.")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>
```

Comment: Indentation is very important in Python. Have you written any Python code before? If not, I recommend you learn the basic syntax first.

Comment: ... This is NOT a function receiving an integer argument ...

Comment: Thanks, I just learned not to ignore the error feedbacks I get.

Comment: I fixed the code 
def fun():
    x =input("Enter a number to check if it is positive,negative or zero:") 
    if int(x) == 0:
        print("The number is zero.")
    elif int(x) > 0: 
        print("The number is positive.")
    elif int(x) < 0:
        print("The number is negative.")
fun()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is very important in Python:

```
if x == 0:
    print("The number is zero.")
```